# How to share Audio and play on facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

Audio which is located on the website and when I share my audio on the facebook, it should share on facebook wall and when I click that audio it should play on the facebook wall.

Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: Can only be done by specifying a flash player that plays the audio file as “video” attachment. Keywords are “feed gaming”, `og:video`. (FB partners such as SoundCloud have different possibilities, but your app/site won’t get those.)

Comment: Can you suggested me some flash player that plays the audio files as video. I already tried the jwplayer but it don't work

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to share audio on the wall.. you can Share the link that copied from the address bar of the audio location on your wall. If you want to play audio files on your wall you must convert it to any video format and upload as a video on your wall. If you share the link, it opens the website that the audio located and play from that site.

Comment: Justin, it is possible as one of the site is already doing the same thing

Comment: Thakyou.. i didn't know that. i thought it is not possible.